# Touchpad drivers for XPS13 9343 / Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: kubuntu, touchpad, dell

Most of my touchpad settings are disabled on Kubuntu 18.04 for the XPS 13 9343.  This is an install from scratch.  I recall the laptop has configured had a Dell ppa.  Does anyone know how to install the touchpad drivers or get the configuration working?  The scrolling seems smooth, I just can't change two finger gestures.  I downloaded the Dell driver pack, but don't see any debs that are touchpad related.

TIA

Answer (score 4):

Should be achieved installing `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`. It's in universe.

Comment: @tim999999999 If you find this answer useful you [may "accept" it](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) (by clicking on the tick mark (✓) next to it) so others may more easily find it in the future.